# Why DetailViewController pop to first DetailViewController with Tabbar and Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image: Green arrow button click action pass data to <code>MyCartVC</code>, Page goes like Red arrows way. I want to go with Blue arrows way.]First of all I am using storyboard. My ViewController hierarchy like this `NavigationController -> SplashScreen -> LoginScreen -> MainTabBarController -> MainNavigationController -> MainViewController -> DetailViewController`.

When I click a button on the `DetailViewController` page does not back to `MainViewController`. It is going to `LoginScreen`.

I tried this codes within `addToBasket` action in `DetailViewController`.

```
@IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {

SingletonCart.sharedFood.food.append(food!)

let mainView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FoodOrder") as! MainViewController
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true)

    }
```

Here is my `loginButton` codes for make `MyTabBarController` as rootViewController.

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
}
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) use  insted of instantiat Food Controller

Comment: Why are you using two statements for going back: `popViewController` & `dismiss`. Use only one `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` not this `dismiss(animated: true)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach the RootViewController is Navigation controller of Login screen therefore this issue occurs.

Your approach should be like as follows:

A) NavigationController -> SplashScreen -> LoginScreen

B) MainTabBarController -> MainNavigationController -> MainViewController -> DetailViewController

When user logged in, you should replace your window.rootViewController with B) MainTabBarController

Comment: When I clicked to `addToBasket` button, I should control login successful or not? If it is not, rootViewController is very first `NavigationController`? If it is rootViewController is `MainTabBarController`?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve same by changing your window.rootViewController from A) to B) and vice versa based on condition.

Comment: I pass datas from DetailVC to MyCartVC with addToBasket button. If I use `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` my datas do not pass to MyCartVC but view controller popping from navigation stack.  If I use `dismiss(animated:)` datas passing to MyCartVC. I just edit my question above. 
@Bhavik Modi

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func addBasket(_ sender: Any) {

        SingletonCart.sharedFood.food.append(food!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
```